# InputStream - read data from serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, inputstream

I have problems reading data from serial port. My code is something like this:

```
 case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        try {
            int numBytes = 0;
            while ((numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer)) >= 0){
                //Some code to process data
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        break;
```

Incoming packages are small, with different size - 5, 7, 13 bytes. Baud rate is 57600. In real environment there are 3-4 packages per second.

The problem is:

- when I'm using `javax.comm, read()` method returns byte array readBytes in which bytes with value 0 are omitted. read() method doesn't read zeros;
- when I'm using `RXTX, numBytes` is with correct value (whole package is read), but only in readBytes[0] there is value.

So, I'm completely stuck and no idea what is going on and where to find the solution.

Can somebody give me at least a hint how to solve this problem?